# Property not found even when specified in deceleration file typescript

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings, .d.ts

When attempting to read a property from an express request object defined in the 'express-request-id' middleware and declared in a typescript declaration file it throws an error.

My d.ts file has the following defined:

(server.d.ts)

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        id: string
    }
}
```

This should be correct. According to my research, the only way this would not work would be bad referencing of it. The way I am referencing it is through the `files` field in my tsconfig like so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "ESNext",
        "watch": true,
        "lib": ["ESNext", "ES7"],
        "types": ["node"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,

    "typeAcquisition": { "enable": true },

    // referenced here.
    "files": ["./server.d.ts"],

    // i have also tryed refrenceing it here and in a triple slash directive.
    "include": [
        "./*.ts",
        "./server/**/*.ts",
        "./shared/**/*.ts",
        "./api/**/*.ts",
        "./database/**/*.ts",
        "./builders/**/*"
    ]
}
```

The pice of code that creates the error is the following:
(server/middleware/reqTerminator.ts)

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

// when testing triple slash directives they wore used here like the folowing:
// /// <reference types="../../server.d.ts" />

export const [completeRequest, middleware] = (() => {
    const connections = new Map<string, NodeJS.Timeout>()

    const completeRequest = async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
        const timeout = connections.get(request.id)
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
        response.end()
        return connections.delete(request.id)
    }

    return [
        completeRequest,
        async (request: Request, response: Response, nextF: NextFunction) => {
            connections.set(
                request.id,
                setTimeout(() => {
                    completeRequest(request, response)
                }, 2000),
            )
            nextF()
        },
    ]
})()

export default middleware
```

the error is:

```
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
server/middleware/reqTerminator.ts:7:43 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

7       const timeout = connections.get(request.id)
                                                ~~
server/middleware/reqTerminator.ts:10:37 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

10      return connections.delete(request.id)
                                          ~~
server/middleware/reqTerminator.ts:17:13 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

17                      request.id,
```

It is being run with ts-node with the corresponding project.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I solved this by instead of using a declaration file using a global declaration internally in the problematic file.
Like so:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

// declaration start:
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            id: string
        }
    }
}


export const [completeRequest, middleware] = (() => {
    const connections = new Map<string, NodeJS.Timeout>()

    const completeRequest = async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
        const timeout = connections.get(request.id)
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
        response.end()
        return connections.delete(request.id)
    }

    return [
        completeRequest,
        async (request: Request, response: Response, nextF: NextFunction) => {
            connections.set(
                request.id,
                setTimeout(() => {
                    completeRequest(request, response)
                }, 2000),
            )
            nextF()
        },
    ]
})()

export default middleware
```